# Why is pressure in a common rail fuel system so much higher than in an air compressor or supercharger?

Tags: automotive-engineering, pressure, compressors

Superchargers in cars are bulky, expensive, consume considerable amount of engine's power and yet they generate only about 6-9 psi boost. On the other hand, modern [common rail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_rail) diesel engines inject fuel into the cylinder at 36,000 psi. Naturally, superchargers handle a much larger volume, but still the discrepancy is shocking. I suppose it is easier to generate pressure with a liquid which is not compressible, but why exactly is that?

Comment: Just consider the differences in volume flow rate, then think about density and viscosity... All the reasons are there.

Comment: @SolarMike a lean air-fuel ratio is 14.7:1. But it is mass ratio. When we convert that to volume ratio, because of the air's 625 times lesser density (compared to gasoline), we get volume ratio of 9187.5:1. Okay, now I think I get it ;)

Comment: Isn't 14.7:1 stoichiometric?

Comment: @SolarMike yes, it is. With a rich mixture the ratio would be less.

Comment: Have you even **looked** at the size difference between a car and a rail locomotive?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_rail

Comment: note that diesel engines do not burn at stochiometric - it is always a lean burn.  The pressure is to ensure proper delivery of fuel & overcome the pressures experienced during combustion - these systems replaced high pressure mechanical injectors.